# Why I read glibc version >= 2.7 while the current stable version of glibc is 2.23

Tags: linux, dpdk

I'm reading the chapter 2.3.1 of [Getting Started Guide for Linux (Release 16.04.0)](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html#running-dpdk-applications), and I just saw :

> Required:
>
> > glibc >= 2.7 (for features related to cpuset)
> >
> > The version can be checked using the ldd --version command.

When I ran `ldd --version` I got

> ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.9) 2.19
>
> Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

Does that mean my glibc version is 2.19?

I've tried some ways to upgrade the version, but got nothing new.

Actually, on [The GNU Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), I noticed

> Latest News
>
> 2016-02-19: glibc 2.23 released.

So how can I get the version of 2.7?? Does Getting Started Guide for Linux (Release 16.04.0) give the wrong message?

Comment: `>=` means greater than or equals to. 2.19 >= 2.7. So you should be good to go as far as the prereqs are concerned.

Comment: @kaylum I found I just mistake 2.19 for 2.1.9. What a stupid mistake:) and thanks a lot!